# Would questions on build styles of certain instruments be acceptable?

Tags: discussion

For example, I have a question concerning the truss rod in a guitar and how it may be accessed at the top of the neck or in the body of the guitar. Would this be an acceptable question to ask?

For example, I would like to know if it is possible to build an electric guitar with access to the truss rod in the body of the guitar rather than at the top of the neck, and how one would go about incorporating this into a guitar build.

Comment: I think this would be on-topic, although it is very easily answered by a quick 2 minute google. Have a look at how Shergold do it: http://www.shergold.co.uk/images/detail/trussrodadj1.jpg and many basses have truss rod access from the front, between the neck and the first pickup.