# Instrument construction

Tags: discussion

Would questions about construction instruments be on topic? I noticed [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374/would-questions-on-build-styles-of-certain-instruments-be-acceptable) that build styles are ok, but I don't think the kinds of questions I'd ask would be so simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construction :)

You may not get the best answers here, since I don't think we have many construction experts yet, but we have to start somewhere!  I believe there was a proposed SE site for instrument construction that didn't gain enough traction, so this is your best bet on SE.