# Are technical questions about the construction of instruments/accessoires on-topic?

Tags: discussion, topics

I am thinking about questions like:

> Is product *x* one of the right components to build end-product *y*?

These questions tend to be pretty specific on the electronical aspect, so should they be on the [Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)? Maybe when you're asking about components for a custom effect pedal construction, but what about getting the correct cable?

The motivation for this question is that I want to know whether I can use a certain type of cable as material for the 'assembly' of a speaker cable (amp head to cab). The question itself can be generalised (instead of too localised) to "what type of 'raw' cable should one use as speaker cable?" and "how should I decide on the gauge?".

I think very specific questions about effect pedal mods should be on the Electrical Engineering SE, but questions which are much more simple could be on Music SE. However, this distinction will be sometimes hard to make, right?

Comment: Interestingly, we just had a question on constructing a recorder: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/45245/what-are-the-technical-measures-of-a-tenor-recorder/45246#45246 The first comment there suggested that it was off-topic, but your question seems a little different. In my opinion yours is on topic, because yours can be generalized and is more obviously about "practice" than the question I cited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After closer examination, this has apparently already been asked [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/560/instrument-construction?rq=1).

In short, there is actually a `construction` tag, so it's certifiably on-topic. Since it's a guitar question, you'll probably get decent feedback (bah-dum, tss).

I'm not a guitar player, so I can't comment specifically on when a question will be more geared towards electrical engineering, but I assume the distinction *would* be hard to make sometimes, as you suggested.